# Sent Folder to be deleted completely?

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to delete the sent folder in Gmail completely?

I have deleted the messages in the sent mail folder but I want to delete the sent mail folder because I find it to be unnecessary and takes up unnecessary space in my Gmail.

Answer (score 2):

### Hide Sent Label

1. In a web browser go to **Gmail Settings** and select the **Labels
   section** ([direct link](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=cm#settings/labels))
2. In the section labelled "**System
   labels**" select "**hide**" (column: "Show in label list")
3. You can also uncheck "Show in IMAP" if you don't want it to show on your devices.

https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?tab=cm#settings/labels

Answer (score 0):

In Gmail the Sent folder can't be deleted as it's a system element but you can "hide" from the left side panel.

The side panel has two sections for Gmail folders, one that is shown all the time and other that is collapsable. The collapse/expanse control might have the lables "Show More" or "Show Less".

1. If the collapsable section shows "Show More", click on this label to expand it.
2. Drag and drop the Sent folder into the collapsable section.
3. Click "Show Less" to hide the collabsable section.